# How do I localize a react-native-web app?

Tags: internationalization, react-native-web

I have an existing react-native-web app that I'm now trying to add localization for. Are there any libraries that make this possible?

Neither react-native-localize (https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-localize) nor the now deprecated react-native-i18n (https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n) seem to work with react-native-web.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the i18next library:

https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next

It's compatible with react-native and I've tested with react-native-web.

Answer (score 0):

Might be in the past that was not a case but nowadays `react-native-localize` has web support according to its page https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-localize

Though I had a problem in just plug-and-play it into the Monorepo project, and the solution was to add this line:

`'./module$': aliasPathJoin(['react-native-localize', 'lib', 'module', 'module.web.js']),`

into webpack's `resolve` / `alias` config.

Note! As that alias pattern is very trivial it might replace something not wanted, so better to check the bundle file after creation.

Full [webpack.config.js](https://github.com/KEMBL/react-native-shop/blob/develop/packages/rns-web-app/webpack.config.js) example (includes `aliasPathJoin` function).